# Fluentd time_key setting not working

Tags: elasticsearch, record, fluentd, transformer-model

Working on trying to use fluentd to centralize mysql logs into elastic search.

The issue I'm seeing is that time timestamp in the search is not matching the timestamp in the log.

Here's my fluentd config:

```bash
<source>
  @type tail
  path /logs/mysql/audit.log
  pos_file /var/log/td-agent/audit.log.pos
  tag mysql.audit
  format json
</source>

<match mysql.audit>
  type elasticsearch
  host isolinear-eg.corp.apple.com
  port 9200
  index_name mysql_audit
  include_tag_key true
  logstash_format true
  logstash_prefix mysql_audit
  time_key audit_record.timestamp
  time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S %Z
  flush_interval 10s # for testing
</match>
```

And here's the output:

```bash
{
  "_index": "mysql_audit-2017.04.18",
  "_type": "fluentd",
  "_id": "AVuBrutMy6H0rNsJZZHy",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "audit_record": {
      "name": "Connect",
      "record": "447474053_2017-04-11T22:30:21",
      "timestamp": "2017-04-18T15:29:01 UTC",
      "connection_id": "21450",
      "status": 0,
      "user": "solver",
      "priv_user": "solver",
      "os_login": "",
      "proxy_user": "",
      "host": "",
      "ip": "10.108.251.201",
      "db": "solver"
    },
    "tag": "mysql.audit",
    "@timestamp": "2017-04-18T10:29:02-05:00"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      1492529342000
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1492529342000
  ]
}
```

The issue I'm seeing is that the timestamp is not matching the audit record timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

For example, a generated log has a time key itself.
[example log format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJKyK.png)

we need to provide the time_key key in the source section.

```
<source>
  @type tail
  path /logs/mysql/audit.log
  pos_file /var/log/td-agent/audit.log.pos
  time_key time
  tag mysql.audit
  format json
</source>
```

if the time_key is not present in the log. fluentd will attach it's log reading time to log.

you didn't specify the time_key in the source section. that's why fluentd is not considering actual log time